# Android Java - ArrayList lowercase

Tags: java, android

I have a string in ArrayList that i want to convert to lowercase before next lines in code utilize this.The string is called 'results' and will not accept .inLowercase within ArrayList method.
How can i convert the result to lowercase, i tried this with no luck as explained:

```
result = result.toLowerCase();
```

i also tried this:

```
Set<String> results2 = new results.toLowerCase();
```

no luck, yes im noob.. =?

Any help would be great.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try looping over each element in the `ArrayList` and substitute the current value with the `toLowerCase` equivalent.

Comment: Do you want only one String to lower case? Or the whole List?

Answer (score -1):

this works:

```
 String[] stringsArray = strings.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<stringsArray.length; ++i)
    {
        stringsArray[i] = stringsArray[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    strings.clear();
    strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(stringsArray));
```

Thank you everybody for helping. Especially stackoverflow's people. =]